# select2 not letting my other scripts work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sir, my ajax isnt loading when i use select2 plugin .
it works fine when i remove it. the blur event is working.
but i want to be able to search in the dropdown, and somehow ajax isnt working 
this part isnt working

```
$("#bank_id").focus();
```

so due to above script not working the blur event in the code below isnt working.

this is the script and html

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Bank<span><font color="red"></font></span></label>
            <select class="form-control select2" name="bank_id" id="bank_id">
          <c:choose>  
            <c:when test="${bankDetailsEdit.bank_id != 0}">
                <option value="${bankDetailsEdit.bank_id }" >${bankDetailsEdit.bankName }</option>
            </c:when>   
            <c:when test="${bankDetailsEdit.bank_id == 0}">
                <option disabled selected>Select Bank</option>
            </c:when>
          </c:choose>    
                <c:forEach var="bank" items="${bankMasterDetails}">
                    <option value="${bank.bank_id}">${bank.bank_name}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Bank Branch Name<span><font color="red"> </font></span></label>
            <select class="form-control select2" name="bankBranchId" id="op1" >
                <option value="${bankDetailsEdit.bankBranchId }" >${bankDetailsEdit.bankBranchName }</option>
                <c:forEach begin="0" end="100" varStatus="loop">
                    <option></option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $('.select2').select2();
    $(document).ready(function(){ /* PREPARE THE SCRIPT */
        $("#bank_id").focus();
        $("#bank_id").on('blur change',function(){ /* WHEN YOU CHANGE AND SELECT FROM THE SELECT FIELD */

          var bank_id = $(this).val(); /* GET THE VALUE OF THE SELECTED DATA */
          var dataString={'bank_id':bank_id}; /* STORE THAT TO A DATA STRING */

          $.ajax({
                type: "GET",

                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/broker/bankBranchDetails",
                data : ({
                    'bank_id':bank_id
                }),

                success: function (bankList) {
                    $('#op1').empty();
                    var opt = '<option disabled selected>Select Branch</option>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < bankList.length; i++) {
                        $('#op1').append(opt);
                        opt = new Option(bankList[i].bank_branch_name,bankList[i].bank_branch_id);

                    }

                   },
                   error: function (request, error) {
                      alert("Unable to fetch bank details");
                   }
              });  

        });

        $("#op1").change(function(){ /* WHEN YOU CHANGE AND SELECT FROM THE SELECT FIELD */

              var branch_id = $(this).val(); /* GET THE VALUE OF THE SELECTED DATA */
              var dataString={'branch_id':branch_id}; /* STORE THAT TO A DATA STRING */

              $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",

                    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/broker/branchIfscDetails",
                    data : ({
                        'branch_id':branch_id
                    }),

                    success: function (data) {
                        var ifsc = data;
                        document.getElementById("ifsc").value=ifsc;

                       },
                       error: function (request, error) {
                          alert("Unable to fetch bank details");
                       }
                  });  

            });

      });
    </script>
```

Comment: the input field isnt getting focussed on page load when i use script of select2

Comment: Do you mean that the `on("blur change")` callback function is not being executed when using select2 but when not using select2 the callback function was being called?

Comment: i am making select box which is labelled as Bank focussed and when it is blurred the ajax loads data on other select box labelled as branch. but on loading the page my bank select box isnt focussed. so theres is no point of blur event here

Comment: when i remove $('.select2').select2(); everything works fine, the bank select box is autofocussed and when i click on other input field blur event fires and data is loaded in branch select box

Comment: hope you understand what i meant

Comment: do you mean `branch select box` is not updated when using `select2`?

Comment: When `select2()` is not included in the script, what is the behavior of the select box?

Comment: bank select box is focussed, and when i click on Bank Branch Name select box, the blur event occurs on Bank select box  and options are loaded in the Bank Branch Name select box through ajax

Comment: these are two dependent select dropdowns here

Comment: the only problem is as to why Bank select dropdown is loosing focus when i use select2. why $("#bank_id").focus(); isnt working?

Comment: yes Iftifar Taz

Comment: `select2` changes the `dom` directly. So probably element with id `bank_id` is not in display anymore. So you can't see the focus effect.

Comment: i even used html attribute autofocus on the select box of bank.it didnt worked

Comment: so what can i do to prevent select2 from doing that

Comment: When you say focus on regular select box, the select box will just be outlined or boxed. With select2, do you also want the select2 box to be outlined or boxed?

Comment: i am only using select2 for searching through options purposes.

Comment: i want other scripts to work normally

Comment: Ok I get it now. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From this page: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events:

> Select2 has an internal event system that works independently of the
>   DOM event system, allowing adapters to communicate with each other.

You are tied to using the plugins event handling mechanism so the first paremeter of the jQuery `on` function needs to be changed.

from `$("#bank_id").on('blur change',function(){`

to `$("#bank_id").on('select2:select',function(){`

Unfortunately `$("#bank_id").focus();` will not work because it is not listed in the available select2 events.

You're `success` callback function in the first event listener, which tries to generate `options` element for the 2nd select box will also not work as select2 has a different way of adding `options` dynamically through AJAX as listed in this page: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Comment: `blue ` and `change` events will still work. `select2` adds extra events to a `dom element`. It does not overwrite them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$('#bank_id').select2('open');` instead of `$("#bank_id").focus();` to open the bank selection on page load.

You can check their [documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/methods).

Comment: i really want #bank_id to be focussed, so on clicking other input fields, it looses focus, and blur event triggers, but there is never a focus on the #bank_id

Comment: #bank_id is still there as change event is happening, but it is still partial. the branch select box shows result only when i click on it.

Comment: what are the alternatives of select2